# How to manipulate substring offset to repeated tag

Tags: java, android, string, api, substring

I'm using the Google API geocode for getting user adress in Android.

The response I get is something like:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<type>street_address</type>
<formatted_address>
R. Dante Marobi, 142 - Colina Verde, Mococa - SP, Brasil
</formatted_address>
<address_component>
<long_name>142</long_name>
<short_name>142</short_name>
<type>street_number</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Rua Dante Marobi</long_name>
<short_name>R. Dante Marobi</short_name>
<type>route</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Colina Verde</long_name>
<short_name>Colina Verde</short_name>
<type>political</type>
<type>sublocality</type>
<type>sublocality_level_1</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Mococa</long_name>
<short_name>Mococa</short_name>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Mococa</long_name>
<short_name>Mococa</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>São Paulo</long_name>
<short_name>SP</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
```

I'm using such structure in order to get ONLY the city name

```
<type> locality
```

to a string, but I don't know how to manipulate the string to get there.

I found a tutorial that teaches to do so, like this:

```
String cidade = resposta.substring(resposta.indexOf("<formatted_adress>" ) + 19, resposta.indexOf( "</formatted_adress>" ));
```

Thing is, I don't want the formatted_address part, I want the adress_component, but there is many address_component tags, and I don't know how to make the offset go to the one referring to the city name.

How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: Best way to process XML text is to use a XML Parser, e.g. [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume the format will always be the same...

You know your city name is always in "locality" block and that it is unique.

```
String[] stuffsplit = stuff.split("<type>locality");
String firstHalf = stuffsplit[0];  // keep everything before that

// now look for the short_name tags at the end of this
int start = firstHalf.lastIndexOf("<short_name>") + "<short_name>".length();
int end = firstHalf.lastIndexOf("</short_name>");
String name = firstHalf.substring(start, end);
```

You can switch out `short_name` for `long_name` if you like.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm!